# How to map offset integer to IANA timezone

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, java-time

Using a system that stores timezone information for historical object as follows:

```
o1:    dt= 2022-07-15 13:32:00  offset=5   dst=false    
o2:    dt= 2022-01-15 13:32:00  offset=5   dst=true     
o3:    dt= 2022-07-15 13:32:00  offset=7   dst=false
```

Life would be much easier if it stored IANA timezones like "America/New York" but this is what I have to deal with.  My end goal is to compare these historical dates to the current time and get a time difference between them.

Creating current time is easy.  I can get it in UTC

```
   ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"))
   2022-07-15T15:33:04.177Z[UTC]
```

Or my local timezone

```
ZonedDateTime.now()
2022-07-15T11:33:28.648-04:00[America/New_York]
```

The question is, how can I read the table data into a `ZonedDateTime` for an apples to apples comparison.  For example some magical method like

`ZonedDateTime.fromOffset(5).fromDst(false).asTz('UTC')`

Comment: Would using `ZoneOffset.ofHours(int hours)` be sufficient? (I don't think DST true/false is relevant). Also, is the timestamp local, or at UTC?

Comment: (BTW your offsets seems to be *negated*- based on prior version: EDT is -5, MST -7 - e.g. if using the first answer)

Comment: ((BTW2 title does not really match the question's body}}

Comment: Thanks I will update the question title.  I will try zoneoffset, had overlooked that

Comment: Just to address the question in the original question title - mapping from an integer to an IANA time zone ID is not possible.  See "time zone != offset" in [the `timezone` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: To whomever devised this data scheme of yours: Offsets are not necessarily a number of whole hours. Offsets can have minutes and even seconds.

Comment: If offset 5 means -05:00, does dst true then imply that the true offset is 1 hour ahead of that, -04:00?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ZoneOffset` with the specified offset, the DST true/false doesn't seem relevant here. Assuming the timestamps are shown are local (and not UTC), you can do something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    record TimestampAndOffset(String timestamp, int offsetHours) { }
    
    var timeData = List.of(
            new TimestampAndOffset("2022-07-15T13:32:00", 5),
            new TimestampAndOffset("2022-01-15T13:32:00", 5),
            new TimestampAndOffset("2022-07-15T13:32:00", 7));

    timeData.forEach(to -> {
        LocalDateTime localTimestamp = LocalDateTime.parse(to.timestamp());
        var zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.ofHours(to.offsetHours());
        var zonedValue = ZonedDateTime.of(localTimestamp, zoneOffset);
        System.out.println(zonedValue);
        System.out.println(zonedValue.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
    });
}
```

To simplify parsing for this example, I use ISO-8601 format with `T` as the separator.

Output:

```
2022-07-15T13:32+05:00
2022-07-15T08:32Z
2022-01-15T13:32+05:00
2022-01-15T08:32Z
2022-07-15T13:32+07:00
2022-07-15T06:32Z
```

Important caveat as pointed out by [user16320675](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16320675/user16320675) in the comments, double check the meaning of your offsets, as based on the [original version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72996432/1) of your question, your data might be using an inverse offset (e.g. 5 instead of -5), in which case you need to use `ZoneOffset.ofHours(-to.offsetHours())` instead.

As mentioned in the comments by Basil Bourque, consider if using `OffsetDateTime` makes more sense for your use case.

Comment: I'm trying to test this out but am stuck on java8.  Where is `record` comding from - this is a Java 14 thing right?  IBecause it has a `toTimestamp()` method I wouldn't have...

Comment: Good Answer. But `ZonedDateTime` here should be `OffsetDateTime`. No time zones involved in this problem & solution.

Comment: @BasilBourque I considered that, but given the OP asked for ZonedDateTime, I used that.

Answer (score 2):

@Mark Rotteveel answered this question.  I had to adapt his answer a bit to fit my exact needs and the constraint of being on Java 8 so am posting my exact solution in case useful.

```
LocalDateTime localDt = LocalDateTime.parse("2022-07-15T13:32:00");
// IF DST MAKE THIS 4
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHours(-5);
OffsetDateTime offsetDt = localDt.atOffset(offset);

// Not sure the canonical way to do a duration check but this seems to work
// Duration d = Duration.between( offsetDt , Instant.now());
Instant now = Instant.now();
boolean isFutureDate = offsetDt.toInstant().getEpochSecond() > now.getEpochSecond();
log.info("Original: {}, OffsetDt:{}, Now: {}, isFutureDate: {}" , localDt, offsetDt, now, isFutureDate);
```

Which outputs

```
Original: 2022-07-15T13:32, OffsetDt:2022-07-15T13:32-05:00, Now: 2022-07-18T16:28:48.384Z, isFutureDate: false
```

Comment: `ZonedDateTime` is the wrong class to use here, misleading as no time zone is involved. We have the `OffsetDateTime` class expressly for your situation.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

You said:

> My end goal is to compare these historical dates to the current time and get a time difference between them.

```java
record History( String dt , int offset , boolean dst ) { }
Instant now = Instant.now();
List.of(
                new History( "2022-07-15 13:32:00" , 5 , false ) ,
                new History( "2022-01-15 13:32:00" , 5 , true ) ,
                new History( "2022-07-15 13:32:00" , 7 , false )
        )
        .forEach(
                history -> System.out.println(
                        Duration.between(
                                LocalDateTime
                                        .parse( 
                                                history.dt().replace( " " , "T" ) 
                                        )
                                        .atOffset(
                                                ZoneOffset.ofHours( history.offset() )
                                        )
                                        .toInstant() ,
                                now
                        )
                )
        );
```

> PT17H4M40.423919S
>
> PT4361H4M40.423919S
>
> PT19H4M40.423919S

## `OffsetDateTime`

The other two Answers [by Mark Rotteveel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72997037/642706) and [by Adam Hughes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73000096/642706) are both basically correct. But they, like the Question, use `ZonedDateTime` rather than the more appropriate class, `OffsetDateTime`. And they do not address the specific parsing needs asked in the Question. And apparently the input data is already in objects, so I will represent that as [records](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395).

```
public record History( String dt , int offset , boolean dst ) { }
```

Populate some data.

```java
List < History > historyList =
        List.of(
                new History( "2022-07-15 13:32:00" , 5 , false ) ,
                new History( "2022-01-15 13:32:00" , 5 , true ) ,
                new History( "2022-07-15 13:32:00" , 7 , false )
        );
```

We need to produce a `java.time.OffsetDateTime` object for each of those inputs. We can add a method to our record to perform that work.

To parse the given inputs, we can either define a `DateTimeFormatter` with a formatting pattern to match, or we can do string manipulation to bring the inputs into compliance with the ISO 8601 standard format used by default in `OffsetDateTime.parse`. I choose the latter. We simply need to replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

As Rotteveel mentioned in his Answer, the boolean for whether Daylight Saving Time (DST) is in effect or not is irrelevant. We ignore that member field in our `History` record.

```java
public record History( String dt , int offset , boolean dst )
{
    OffsetDateTime toOffsetDateTime ( )
    {
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( this.dt.replace( " " , "T" ) );
        ZoneOffset o = ZoneOffset.ofHours( this.offset );
        OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( o );
        return odt;
    }
}
```

Capture the current moment.

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
```

Your goal is to determine elapsed time. Use `Duration` for that. We can add another method to `History` record for that purpose.

```java
package work.basil.example.history;

import java.time.*;

public record History( String dt , int offset , boolean dst )
{
    OffsetDateTime toOffsetDateTime ( )
    {
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( this.dt.replace( " " , "T" ) );
        ZoneOffset o = ZoneOffset.ofHours( this.offset );
        OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( o );
        return odt;
    }

    Duration elapsed ( final Instant instant )
    {
        Duration d = Duration.between( this.toOffsetDateTime().toInstant() , instant );
        return d;
    }
}
```

Loop the inputs to report their elapsed time.

```java
Instant now = Instant.now();
for ( History history : historyList )
{
    String message = history.elapsed( now ).toString() + " from " + history.toString() + " to " + now.toString();
    System.out.println( message );
}
```

When run.

```
PT16H27M40.119075S from History[dt=2022-07-15 13:32:00, offset=5, dst=false] to 2022-07-16T00:59:40.119075Z
PT4360H27M40.119075S from History[dt=2022-01-15 13:32:00, offset=5, dst=true] to 2022-07-16T00:59:40.119075Z
PT18H27M40.119075S from History[dt=2022-07-15 13:32:00, offset=7, dst=false] to 2022-07-16T00:59:40.119075Z
```

Comment: Thank you for tieing everything together here